# Why am I losing some records in dataframe after transformation in PySpark compare to Pythonic version?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a newbie in PySpark, and I want to add a new column that contains/reports normalized statistic frequency of features for each record/row/event in PySpark on *synthetic* data. (Columns `Type` & `Encoding_type` are categorical)  At first, I have Spark data frame so-called `sdf`  including 5 columns:

Below is the example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("Sentence",92,6,"False",49),
         ("Sentence",17,3,"False",15),
         ("Sentence",17,3,"False",15),
         (0         , 0,0,"False", 0),
         (0         , 0,0,"False", 0),
         (0         , 0,0,"False", 0)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Type",              StringType(),  True), \
    StructField("Length",            IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Token_number",      IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("Encoding_type",     StringType(), True), \
    StructField("Character_feature", IntegerType(), True) \
    
  ])
 
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
sdf.printSchema()
sdf.show(truncate=False)

#root
# |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Length: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- Token_number: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- Encoding_type: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Character_feature: integer (nullable = true)

#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
#|Type    |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|
#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
#|Sentence|92    |6           |False        |49               |
#|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |
#|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |
#|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
#|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
#|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to allocate *statistic frequency* of features and map them to the main frame `sdf` as follows:

```py
#Statistical Preprocessing
def add_freq_to_features_(df):
  sdf_pltc = sdf.select('Type', 'Length', 'Token_number', 'Encoding_type', 'Character_feature')
  #sdf_pltc.show(truncate=0)

  sdf2 = (
      sdf_pltc
      .groupBy(sdf_pltc.columns)
      .agg(F.count('*').alias('Freq'))
    # .withColumn('Freq' , (col('Freq')  / col('Freq').sum()))    # Normalzing between 0 & 1
      .withColumn('Encoding_type', F.col('Encoding_type').cast('string'))
      
      
  )

  sdf2.show()
  
  return new_df

# Apply frequency allocation and merge with extracted features df
features_df = add_freq_to_features_(df)
features_df

#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
#|    Type|Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|Freq|
#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
#|Sentence|    92|           6|        False|               49|   1|
#|       0|     0|           0|        False|                0|   3|
#|Sentence|    17|           3|        False|               15|   2|
#+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
```

So as it can be seen compared with the pythonic version due to `groupby()` mechanism, it is framed as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type':              ["Sentence" , "Sentence" ,"Sentence" , "-", "-", "-"], 
        'Length':            [92, 17,17,0,0,0],
        'Token_number':      [6, 3,3,0,0,0],
        'Encoding_type':     ["False" , "False" ,"False" , "False", "False", "False"], 
        'Character_feature': [49, 15,15,0,0,0],
       }

# pass column names in the columns parameter 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#df

#Statistical Preprocessing
def add_freq_to_features(df):
  frequencies_df = df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().to_frame().rename(columns={0: "Freq"})
 # frequencies_df["Freq"] = frequencies_df["Freq"] / frequencies_df["Freq"].sum() # Normalzing 0 & 1
  new_df = pd.merge(df, frequencies_df, how='left', on=list(df.columns))
  
  return new_df

features_df = add_freq_to_features(df)
features_df

#+----------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----+
#|Type      |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|Freq |
#+----------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+-----+
#|Sentence  |92    |6           |False        |49               |1    |
#|Sentence  |17    |3           |False        |15               |2    |
#|Sentence  |17    |3           |False        |15               |2    |
#|-         |0     |0           |False        |0                |3    |
#|-         |0     |0           |False        |0                |3    |
#|-         |0     |0           |False        |0                |3    |
#+----------+-----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----+
```

I couldn't figure out how I could reach the Pythonic frame in PySpark. I might mess up in something in functions.

So I kindly provided a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1onCCgkEn7ggT9LU35_1Spg6rfR_nhDRq?usp=sharing) for quick debugging and commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a group by with the count, I would recommend using `count` as a window function to maintain the same amount of records and a result similar to the purely pythonic approach.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


def add_freq_to_features_(df):

  from pyspark.sql import Window

  sdf_pltc = sdf.select('Type', 'Length', 'Token_number', 'Encoding_type', 'Character_feature')
  sdf_pltc.show(truncate=0)

  sdf2 = (
      sdf_pltc.withColumn(
          'Freq',
          F.count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(sdf_pltc.columns))
      )
    # .withColumn('Freq' , (col('Freq')  / col('Freq').sum()))    # Normalzing between 0 & 1
      .withColumn('Encoding_type', F.col('Encoding_type').cast('string'))
      
      
  )

  sdf2.show()
  
  return sdf2

# Apply frequency allocation and merge with extracted features df
features_df = add_freq_to_features_(sdf)
```

#### Edit 1

The order of rows cannot be assumed in spark due to the distributed nature of shuffles and partitioning during operations. As such, we must explicitly specify how to order the rows after each operation. You could share what your dataset is ordered by and I may update the answer. I have demonstrated this with ordering by `Type` then `Length` in descending order.

If there are `null` values, you may replace them with a default value of `0`  using `df.na.fill(0)`.

```py
#ggordon
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window


def add_freq_to_features_(df):

  from pyspark.sql import Window
  sdf_pltc = sdf.select('Type', 'Length', 'Token_number', 'Encoding_type', 'Character_feature')
  print("Before Any Modification") # only included for debugging purposes
  sdf_pltc.show(truncate=0)

  # fill missing values with 0 using `na.fill(0)` before applying count as window function
  sdf2 = (
      sdf_pltc.na.fill(0).withColumn(
          'Freq',
          F.count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(sdf_pltc.columns)) 
      ).withColumn(
          'MaxFreq',
          F.max('Freq').over(Window.partitionBy())
      ).withColumn(
          'MinFreq',
          F.min('Freq').over(Window.partitionBy())
      )
  )
  print("After replacing null with 0 and counting by partitions") # only included for debugging purposes
  # use orderby as your last operation, only included here for debugging purposes
  sdf2 = sdf2.orderBy(F.col('Type').desc(),F.col('Length').desc() )
  sdf2.show(truncate=False) # only included for debugging purposes
  sdf2 = (
      sdf2.withColumn('Freq' , F.when(
           F.col('MaxFreq')==0,0
           ).otherwise(
              (F.col('Freq')-F.col('MinFreq')) / (F.col('MaxFreq') - F.col('MinFreq'))
           )  
      )    # Normalzing between 0 & 1
  )
  sdf2 = sdf2.drop('MinFreq').drop('MaxFreq')
  sdf2 = sdf2.withColumn('Encoding_type', F.col('Encoding_type').cast('string'))
  sdf2 = sdf2.orderBy(F.col('Type').desc(),F.col('Length').desc() )
  print("After normalization, encoding transformation and order by ") # only included for debugging purposes
  sdf2.show(truncate=False)
  

  
  return sdf2
```

***Outputs***

```
Before Any Modification
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|Type    |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|Sentence|92    |6           |False        |49               |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+

After replacing null with 0 and counting by partitions
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+-------+-------+
|Type    |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|Freq|MaxFreq|MinFreq|
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+-------+-------+
|Sentence|92    |6           |False        |49               |1   |3      |1      |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |2   |3      |1      |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |2   |3      |1      |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |3   |3      |1      |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |3   |3      |1      |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |3   |3      |1      |
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+-------+-------+

After normalization, encoding transformation and order by 
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
|Type    |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|Freq|
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
|Sentence|92    |6           |False        |49               |0.0 |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |0.5 |
|Sentence|17    |3           |False        |15               |0.5 |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |1.0 |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |1.0 |
|0       |0     |0           |False        |0                |1.0 |
+--------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I just tested in provided [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1onCCgkEn7ggT9LU35_1Spg6rfR_nhDRq?usp=sharing) and it gives `TypeError: count() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'`

Comment: @Mario I updated the solution to `count("*")` and tested in your [cola notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1onCCgkEn7ggT9LU35_1Spg6rfR_nhDRq?usp=sharing#scrollTo=kXaOmshtNJk4) and also saved changes. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I checked the notebook and updated with some comments. there are some small problems I addressed and left comments. current solution reordered the rows!! another issue is I look for inexpensive way to get normalized column for statistic frequency. another point is what if we have Null values in dataframe then your solution doesn't work out!

Comment: @Mario I've updated the answer and [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1onCCgkEn7ggT9LU35_1Spg6rfR_nhDRq?usp=sharing#scrollTo=A0kH3mrnxzjQ) with additional approaches and questions. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for update and your insightful inputs but after I passed recent updated output of 1st function by you to 2nd function. Despite having right output, surprisingly I faced an error which I couldn't fix it yet, if you check the notebook, I commented ! I'm struggling with it and I don't understand why!!  It's like I can't used the results for any further purpose or function! I can't even run `df.count()`

Comment: @Mario I changed `temp_sdf= sdf_normalized_features_df.show(10,False)` in function `normalize_features_(df)` to `temp_sdf= sdf_normalized_features_df` and `temp_sdf.show()` as `show` would store `None` in `temp_sdf` as you had it before. Now you may update the value that will be returned and print the output in the following line